# Visual Studio 2015 not taking forever to display project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Something really weird is happening with my installation of Visual Studio 2015. When I just opened VS and run the project, it deploys normally. However, when I start to change things i.e. html, js, etc and hit refresh to see my new changes, after a while the browser takes FOREVER to load the page again.

This also happens when I change server code, suppose the project is running normally, then I stop the debugger, change my code, and launch the project again.

I have Windows 10 installed in my machine, Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

I don't know what could be happening, and I have googled it without much success. Does somebody know a way I could inspect what is happening when this occurs? Any tools?

Comment: Without an error message it's hard to say. But you can try disabling certain extensions one by one and see if it helps.

Comment: Do you have ReSharper? or any of the Telerik/Devexpress etc toolls?

Comment: Is your Visual studio taking forever to display a project or not??

Comment: I have resharper installed @A.BurakErbora

Comment: after using for a while it takes forever @Vini